# Bash: Check if a string looks like a three part version number using a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I need bash to check whether `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` matches either the string `master`, or a three part version number like `1.3.5`, `1.1.11` and so on.

Here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=1.1.4
if [ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'master' ] || [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ ^([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$ ]]
 then 
     echo "true"
 else 
     echo "false"
fi
```

The expected output is `true`, but I get `false`. Setting the variable to `master` works as intended, so the mistake must be my regex.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the regex as a separate variable inside single quotes, there will be no issues parsing your regex in bash then and make sure the parentheses are placed around the `[0-9]{1,2}\.` part:

```
rx='^([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$'
if [ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'master' ] || [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ $rx ]]
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/b7jSkU)

Now, the pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}`  - 2 occurrences of 1 or 2 digits followed with a literal dot
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I added the pattern description. And yes, the parentheses should enclose only the pattern you need to quantify.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to match the beginning of the line twice:

```
$ CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=1.1.4
$ [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ (^[0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$ ]] && echo match
$ [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ ^([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}$ ]] && echo match
match
```

Comment: So there were actually two mistakes. Thank you!